# Change Index of Directory

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I'm working on an ASP.NET MVC web application. By default, browsing to the root of a directory seems to call the controller's `Index()` method. Is there way to change which method is called by default here? I know I could probably name the method I want to call "Index" and it would likely work, but I'd like to know if there's a way to point the directory root to a method that I choose.

For example: `mysite.com/MyDirectory/` will call `Index()`, which is effectively browsing to `mysite.com/MyDirectory/Index`. I'd like to change it so that `mysite.com/MyDirectory/` calls `Details`, (or "browses" to `mysite.com/MyDirectory/Details`).

Comment: Adjust the defaults in your `RouteConfig.cs` file so the default `action = "Details"` rather than `"Index"`

Answer (score 0):

Just change the action in the default route. Something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    "Default", // Route name
    "{controller}/{action}/{id}", // URL with parameters
    new { controller = "Home", action = "Details", id = UrlParameter.Optional } // Parameter defaults
);
```

Comment: Wouldn't that change for all URLs though?

Comment: @rar It would.  If you had another URL that you wanted to go to index as normal, it would instead try to go to details

Comment: It depends on the routes defined and the order they are defined. The first route matches. More specific ones will precede this one.

Answer (score 0):

You could specify the behavior in your routes.  If you are using the latest version of MVC, that would be in your **\App_Start\RouteConfig.cs**

You would have something like:

```
        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "MyDirectory",
            url: "MyDirectory",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyDirectory", action = "Details" });
```

You would place this before your default route, as your route table acts kind of like a switch statement matching on the first route that it finds.

```
    public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "MyDirectory",
            url: "MyDirectory",
            defaults: new { controller = "MyDirectory", action = "Details" });

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
        );
    }
```